# Align Buttons in GridLayout

Tags: android, android-button, gravity, grid-layout

My layout code and its graphical representation is:

[image]

This is just an example, I have about 30 `Buttons` in my application inside a `GridLayout`.
I want my `Buttons` to fill their entire cell in the grid and the grid's columns should be in even width/height.

I cant seem to get it done, any help would be welcome.

Comment: why don't you use linear-layout, you can place all buttons in proper heigth and width.

Comment: This is basically a calculator application, so grid layout seems best (I've experimented with linear/relative layout but a grid suits me better)

Comment: How exactly do you want to place all the 30 Buttons? It should be a matrix of n X m Buttons, all being square(equal width and height)?

Comment: http://s18.postimage.org/i7rgp7tnb/Untitled_2.jpg  
This is my actual layout, as you can see the rightmost column is wider than the others, i need all columns to be the same width and for each button to fill it's cell entirely.
the result should be that the grid layout fills the entire screen and each of its buttons has is as big as it can get.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't use `GridLayout` to much to recommend something about using it, what I can recommend you is to use a `TableLayout`. I say this because your layout fits in the `TableLayout`'s scope pretty well and after a quick browsing of `GridLayout`'s documentation this seems like a problem:

*GridLayout does not provide support for the principle of weight, as defined in weight. In general, it is not therefore possible to configure a GridLayout to distribute excess space between multiple components.*

Also `GridLayout` was introduced in `ICS`.

You can see an example for your layout using `TableLayout` here:

https://gist.github.com/3788301

If you don't want the table to fill the entire height then remove the `weigthSum` property from the `TableLayout` and `layout_weight="1"` from the `TableRows`.

Comment: @aviran If my answer helped you could accept it by clicking the check mark. This way the question will become answered , we'll get some reputation points and you're more likely to get users to help you in the future.

Comment: While GridLayout was introduced in ICS, it exists in the v7 support library as well.

Answer (score 2):

With API level 21+ you can use `layout_rowWeight` and `layout_columnWeight`:

```
 <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

    </GridLayout>
```