# GridLayout get buttons to fit area

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I am designing a game for android.  The code already works, but I am having some issues with the UI side of things.  All the Layout types are confusing and never seem to have their attributes helpfully defined.  Essentially, I am looking to make my buttons, that are being added programmatically, fill out the entire space at the bottom of the screen cleanly.  There could be between 2 and 6 buttons, depending on the difficulty setting the player chooses.  But ultimately, I would even just settle for a  layout that fits all 6 buttons evenly here.  I am not exactly sure why this does not fill out the whole area indicated by the .xml designer.  I have tried to provide the relevant parts below, but happy to add additional details on request.

[image: Game Image]

This is the initial XML for the grid layout

```
  <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="182dp"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:id="@+id/buttonsLayout"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></GridLayout>
```

[image: GridLayout]

And setting up the buttons here:

```
private static void setButtons() {
    for (int i = 0; i < GlobalValues.numberOfColors; i++) {
        Button b = new Button(mainActivity);
        ImageView IV = new ImageView(mainActivity);
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                IV.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
                b.setId(i);
                break;
            case 1:
                IV.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
                b.setId(i);
                break;
            case 2:
                IV.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                b.setId(i);
                break;
            case 3:
                IV.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
                b.setId(i);
                break;
            case 4:
                IV.setImageResource(R.drawable.purple);
                b.setId(i);
                break;
            case 5:
                IV.setImageResource(R.drawable.cyan);
                b.setId(i);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        b.setBackgroundDrawable(IV.getDrawable());
        b.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                UI.UpdateColor(view);
            }
        });

        buttonsLayout.addView(b);
    }
}
```

And finally, here is what it currently looks like.  It is clearly not making use of the whole area very well, and I am not sure why.

Comment: do you know that there's an ImageButton in android? Why do you need both the button and the imageview?

Comment: @Gavriel TBH I didn't.  That'll save me some lines of code to be sure!

Comment: Another thing you might think of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601433/align-buttons-in-gridlayout I know it's not exactly your case, but you stated that for now it's good enough to solve it for 6 buttons, so this might work. BTW if I were you I would have different layouts depending on the number of buttons to make them nice. But starting with 6 is the way

Comment: @Gavriel a quick and dirty edit lead me to this http://imgur.com/2UuXeAX
I just haven't worked with any GUI stuff before this, so it's all sorta greek to me.

Comment: @Gavriel nevermind, I think the stuff you have linked me to is enough to get this working.  Post your comment as an answer so I can select it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Align Buttons in GridLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601433/align-buttons-in-gridlayout) might help you. I know it's not exactly your case, but you stated that for now it's good enough to solve it for 6 buttons, so this might work. BTW if I were you I would have different layouts depending on the number of buttons to make them nice. But starting with 6 is the way.